# Changing Icon Size in splash screen

Tags: android, xml, icons, splash-screen

```
<item
    android:drawable="@color/colorIcon"/>

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        />
</item>
```

This is my code for my splash screen but the icon that is used in the splash is too small, I would like help as to how to resize the icon. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try android:gravity="fill_vertical | fill_horizontal" ?

Comment: It works but the icon got stretched too much and looks pixelated.

Comment: I guess this is an interesting link for you https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-ImageView